# MySql transactions: Why SELECT is allowed while CREATE TABLE (SELECT) is not?

Tags: mysql

I have an innoDB-Table. I'm doing in the first thread:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT 1 FROM t GROUP BY 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
UPDATE t SET ...=...;
```

After that, I do in the second thread:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * from t LIMIT 10;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 10);
```

My problem: While SELECT * from t LIMIT 10; in the 2nd thread works without problems, the same selection into the tmp-table blocks it. Why is this the case?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html says:
*Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels.*
But what are these "certain transaction isolation levels" and is there a way to avoid it without "manually" SELECTing all data from t and INSERT it into tmp?

Answer (score 0):

It works when using:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 10);
```

Then it's not blocked, but might contain old data (which is okay in my case).